# Replace spaces with hyphens with str_replace

Tags: php

```
$tag = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['tag']);
$tag = str_replace("-", " ", $_GET['tag']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name = '$tag'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

if (!mysql_num_rows($query)) exit('That tag dont exist.');
```

I have a tag with spaces in its name, how should I do to replace the spaces with hyphens?
I think the above code should work but it does not.

**Update:**

```
$tag = str_replace(' ', '-', $_GET['tag']);
$tag = mysql_real_escape_string($tag);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name = '$tag'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

if (!mysql_num_rows($query)) exit('That tag dont exist');
```

**Db tags**

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL



INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'test'),
(2, 'test test'),
(3, 'test test test test');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (3, 'test test test test');

Either store the tags with hypens instead of spaces, `(3, 'test-test-test-test')`
or store **and** query them with spaces.

`$tag = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['tag']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name = '$tag'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if ( false===($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) ) exit('No such tag.');`

Answer (score 4):

Other way around:

```
$tag = str_replace(' ', '-', $_GET['tag']);
$tag = mysql_real_escape_string($tag);
```

(When you see `str_replace(A, B, C)`, think "replace A with B in C")

(Also, escaping the string should happen *after* everything else. And you accidentally used `$_GET['tag']` instead of `$tag` your second time.)

Comment: thank you that looks good but im sad to say that it still dont work ;/ weird